# Boost shared pointer "runtime error" after it gets end of scope

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I am practicing with boost and now I am testing boost shared pointers. I have a Util class which can read files. After I read the file, my "Read" method gives back a boost::shared_ptr which points to the file content. Then I pass this shared pointer to my Parser class, which parses the string line by line. After the parsing is done, then at the end of my Parser class constructor (at '}') I get a "runtime error" which points to a boost header file. More specifically to checked_delete.hpp to the "delete x" line:

```
template<class T> inline void checked_delete(T * x) {
   // intentionally complex - simplification causes regressions
   typedef char type_must_be_complete[ sizeof(T)? 1: -1 ];
   (void) sizeof(type_must_be_complete);
   delete x;
}
```

A simplifyed code looks something like this:

```
class File {
    string _path;
public:
    File(string path)
    ~File()
    void Open();
    boost::shared_ptr<string> Read();
    void Close();
};

class Parse {
public:
    Parse(string path) {
        File file = File(path);
        file.Open();
        boost::shared_ptr<string> fileContentPtr = file.Read();
        StartParsing(fileContentPtr);
        file.Close();
    }
    ~Parse();
    StartParsing(boost::shared_ptr<string> fileContentPtr);
};

int main() {
string path = "<some path to my file>";
Parse(path);
}
```

Anybody can give me a hint, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: My Read() function:

```
boost::shared_ptr<string> File::Read() {
    if(file.is_open()) {
        ostringstream stream;
        stream << file.rdbuf();
        string content = stream.str();
        boost::shared_ptr<string> contentPtr(&content);
        return contentPtr;
    }
    else {
        throw std::runtime_error("File isn't opened");
    }
}
```

Where "file" variable is a std::fstream file which is used in Open()

Comment: Can you post the `Read()` function definition.

Comment: Do you get the problem with your simplified code also? What's the implementation of File::Read? I don't see an immediate issue with the implementation of the Parse constructor so my guess is that the problem might be connected to File::Read.

Comment: As an unrelated aside, I would strongly recommend passing the 'path' parameter to the Parse constructor by const reference to avoid the unnecessary copy that you're making.

Comment: Yes, I am adding it as const, just forgot it, when I was typing it. I will add my Read() function in a second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The contained object of the `boost::shared_ptr` must be dynamically allocated,
either explicitly via `new` or implicitly via [`boost::make_shared<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html). From [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm):

> **The shared_ptr class template stores a pointer to a dynamically allocated object**, typically with a C++ new-expression. The object pointed to is guaranteed to be deleted when the last shared_ptr pointing to it is destroyed or reset.

In this case, the `std::string` instance is stack allocated and will
be destructed when `Read()` returns:

```
string content = stream.str();
boost::shared_ptr<string> contentPtr(&content);
```

This results in the `shared_ptr` having a dangling pointer and an attempt
to `delete` it when the `shared_ptr` goes out of scope, causing the error.

The program already has undefined behaviour as any code that attempts to access
the `shared_ptr` after `Read()` is dereferencing a dangling pointer.

To correct, dynamically allocate the `std::string`:

```
return boost::make_shared<std::string>(stream.str());
```

Or, simpler, just return and store a `std::string` instance instead:

```
return stream.str();
```

as the compiler should be able to use [return value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

---

Note that c++11 introduced [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), `std::shared_ptr` among them.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Let's pretend that I am working with large txt files, isn't that a waste to copy that string all the time? This might be a silly question. :)

Comment: @Silex, the compiler might optimize it away using [VRO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (or in c++11 it might be `move()`d if NVRO is not possible).